# Error: Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have a C# DLL with a function (ZeorCurveDLL_Excel) that takes arrays as arguments. I try to call it in Excel VBA. But my VBA code won't compile and I keep getting this error at the line of calling this function. I can view this DLL function in VBA Object browser and it looks fine there (I mean every arguments is recognized in the Object browser). I searched the questions and didn't find directly related. Any helps are appreciated. I added a simple test function test_sum and it worked fine in VBA call.

My segment of C# code is here

```
        public int ZeroCurveDLL_Excel(int StartDay, int NumOfMonths, double[] MonthlyRate, int[] MonthlyTerm, double[] YearlyRate, int[] YearlyTerm, int[] DCDateSeq, double[] BootstrapRate)
        {
            long[] MonTerm = new long[MonthlyTerm.Length];
            long[] YrTerm = new long[YearlyTerm.Length];
            long[] DtSeq = new long[DCDateSeq.Length];

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < MonthlyTerm.Length; i++) { MonTerm[i] = MonthlyTerm[i]; }
            for (i = 0; i < YearlyTerm.Length; i++) { YrTerm[i] = YearlyTerm[i]; }
            for (i = 0; i < DCDateSeq.Length; i++) { DtSeq[i] = DCDateSeq[i]; }

            long x = ZeroCurveDLL(StartDay, NumOfMonths, MonthlyRate, MonTerm, YearlyRate, YrTerm, DtSeq, BootstrapRate);
            return (int)x;
        }

        public double test_sum(double a, double b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
```

My VBA code to call the functions are below

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startday As Date
    Dim numofmon As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, x As Long
    Dim arrMonRate() As Variant, arrMonTerm() As Variant
    Dim arrYrRate() As Variant, arrYrTerm() As Variant
    Dim arrDtSeq() As Variant, arrRate() As Variant
    Dim x1 As Double, x2 As Double, z As Double
    
    Dim spline As Interest_Rate_Curve.spline
    Set spline = New Interest_Rate_Curve.spline

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        .Range("J3:J" & .Range("J3").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        startday = .Cells(3, 1).Value2
        numofmon = .Cells(3, 2).Value
        arrMonTerm = .Range("C3:C" & .Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row).Value
        arrMonRate = .Range("D3:D" & .Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row).Value
        arrYrTerm = .Range("E3:E" & .Range("E3").End(xlDown).Row).Value
        arrYrRate = .Range("F3:F" & .Range("F3").End(xlDown).Row).Value
        arrDtSeq = .Range("G3:G" & .Range("G3").End(xlDown).Row).Value2
        arrRate = .Range("H3:H" & .Range("H3").End(xlDown).Row).Value
        
        x = spline.ZeroCurveDLL_Excel(startday, numofmon, arrMonRate, arrMonTerm, arrYrRate, arrYrTerm, arrDtSeq, arrRate)
        
        x1 = 15.6
        x2 = 56.9
        z = spline.test_sum(x1, x2)
        MsgBox (z)
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of how the function look like in VBA Object Browser.
[image: Here is a screenshot of how the function look like in VBA Object Browser]

Comment: You are passing arrays of type `Variant` to a method that expects arrays of type `double` or `int` (`Long` in VBA). You mention a function test_sum. Can you add its code to your question?

Comment: Its likely you will need to use the C# 'dynamic' type rather than typed arrays in your dll function signature. If C~ is being really picky you may then need to explicitly cast the dynamic types to the appropriate types arrays. Remember that if you are coming from excel what you think is a long, may actually be a double.

Comment: @freeflow as `Variant`s, they might be anything, but if they're declared in the VBA code as `Long`, then they will certainly not be anything else.

Comment: @Craig  Please read the OP's code.  The arrays being passed to C# have been declared as variant() and are obtained from Excel Ranges.  C# introduced the dynamic type precisely for this situation, but from the wider com perspective.  Attempting to read an excel range into an array declared as long will give you a runtime error.  You have to read excel ranges into variant arrays.  Checking the subtype of each element in an array is where you will find that for numbers, the underlying type is double and not long.

Comment: You also need to be aware that the variant arrays you are getting from excel will be 2D arrays even if you only specify a column or row and that the Lbound of the arrays will always be 1.  For this reason, if you are reading in just a row or column you need to encapsulate the read in the WorkSheetFunction.Tanspose method. (Once for columns and twice for rows) E.g. 'arrMonTerm = WorksheetFUnction.Transpose( .Range("C3:C" & .Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row).Value) will give an array dimensioned 1 to X, rather than 1 to X,1 to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I did more research and figured it out. Here are two key points:

1. For any array arguments in the C# function, I need to add the key word "ref" before it in the function signature, such as `public int test_array_sum(ref int[] arr1, ref int[] arr2)`. With this change, the compile error as in the thread title is gone. This may look a little odd because in C#, the arrays are passed by ref by default. But it did solve the compile error in VBA code.
2. As several of you pointed out in the comments above, I need to make sure the variable type passing into the dll function matches the function signature interpreted by the VBA. For example, the `int` in C# corresponds to `Long` in VBA, I have to make sure the `arr1()` as a `Long` type in my VBA code before I call the function. With this taken care of, the code won't complain about type mismatch.

With the two changes, the dll functions can be called and work as expected. Hope this will be helpful to other folks experiencing similar issues.